Download file from AWS S3 presigned url in React
I'm having issues trying to download a file from AWS S3 using a presigned URL in React. I can get it to open the file in a new screen but I don't want that. I need it to download to the downloads folder.
This is my current implementation:
downloadFile(payload).then((res) => {
  const url =  URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.url]));
  const link = document.createElement('a');

  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', res.fileName);

  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
});



If the user is having a browser with PDF reading capabilities (or a plugin) and the corresponding settings to open PDF files in-browser, the PDF will open like that.

See: How to force a Download File prompt instead of displaying it in-browser with HTML?
Are you specifically dealing with PDFs? Or does this happen for all files?

I'm dealing with PDFs, XLSX files, JPGs, and PNGs
